# Redis load from aof and continue only in-memory

Tags: redis

I configured a Redis instance to operate only in memory (no data are dumped to a persistent storage) by commenting out the `save` commands:

```
################################ SNAPSHOTTING  ################################

# save 900 1
# save 300 10
# save 60 10000
```

Now when I start my instance, Redis checks if there is any data the file `dump.rdb`. If yes, then it loads the data and the execution continues only in-memory.

Is there a way for me to load previous data from `appendonly.aof` (append only mode) and then continue only in an "in-memory only mode"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - AOF loading upon startup (unlike RDB) is done if and only if `appendonly` is not set to `no`. What you could do, as a workaround, is set `appendonly` to `yes` in the `redis.conf` file and once the server is up and running issue a `CONFIG SET appendonly no` to turn it off.